# Does anyone know a fix for VBA Converter for Excel 2013?

Tags: vba, excel, office-2013, excel-2013

We have a program that outputs an old excel format. When we used Excel 2010, we had to use a Microsoft Hotfix that allowed the old formats to be converted, found here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/926430 ... the fix says it should work in 2013, but I haven't had any luck. My hunch is that there is not a VBA 7 folder as described, but a VBA 7.1 folder instead. 32-bit systems. (I'm aware that the link says for 64-bit, it contains a 32 and 64-bit fix.) Hopefully someone has already run into this problem and has some advice!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is going to continue being a problem with each release of Office. Why not update the offending code? And the link specifically states that the hotfix doesn't work with 64-bit versions of Excel

Answer (score 1):

It should work the same as 2010, and yes you drop the DLLs into the VBA7.1 folder instead of the VBA7 folder.